# Scala object that extends Java class

Tags: scala

An old trick I used in my previous Java projects was to create e.g. a `FileUtils` class that offered helper functions for common file operations needed by my project and not covered by e.g. `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`. Therefore my custom `FileUtils` would extend `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` and offer all their functions as well.

Now I try to do the same in Scala but the apache helper functions are not seen through my `FileUtils` Scala object, what is wrong here?

```
import org.apache.commons.io.{ FileUtils => ApacheFileUtils }

object FileUtils extends ApacheFileUtils {
   // ... additional helper methods
}

val content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/tmp/whatever.txt"))
```

here the compiler complains that `readFileToString` is not a member of my Scala `FileUtils` but it is of `ApacheFileUtils` and I extend from it ...

Comment: I'm guessing `readFileToString` is a static method in Java, so it wouldn't be inherited by extending that class.

Comment: Indeed, `readFileToString` is a static method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Scala equivalent of a class with static methods is an object, so in Scala terms, the static components of `FileUtils` are seen as

```
object FileUtils {
  def readFile(s:String) = ???
  ...
}
```

And in Scala, you can't extend an object.  This is illegal:

```
object A
object B extends A // A is not a type
```

Therefore `object FileUtils extends ApacheFileUtils` only gives you access to the class-level definitions of ApacheFileUtils (that except for the base `Object` methods like `equals` and `hashCode`, you have none)

You might find that Scala offers more elegant ways of providing extensions. Have a look at the ['pimp up my library'](https://coderwall.com/p/k_1jzw) pattern for good starting point.

To apply this pattern to your example:

```
// definition of your "pimped" methods
import java.io.File

class RichFile(file:File) {
  def readToString():String = ???
}

// companion object defines implicit conversion 
object RichFile { 
  implicit def fileToRichFile(f:File):RichFile = new RichFile(f)
}
```

// Usage

```
import RichFile._

val content = new File("/tmp/whatever.txt").readToString
```

Comment: A better suggestion might be `implicit class RichFile(...) extends AnyVal`.  I'm not sure people say "pimp my lib" anymore; but I'm pretty sure they never said "pimp up." :)

Comment: @som-snytt `extends AnyVal` +1. How do you bring the implicit into context when you do implicit class? I personally find the companion object method quite clean and somehow explicit.  "pimp up" -> :-)

Comment: package object is ideal for implicit classes. If the package is enclosing, you do "package foo ; package bar" to pick up foo._, otherwise, the explicit import foo._.